# Need help with Moclix ads

Tags: java, android, ads, mobclix

I have some questions about Mobclix:

I integrated some ads in my app and i can succefully see the test ads.

1: The Mobclix declaration in the manifest requires an application ID:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.mobclix.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="insert-your-application-key"/>
```

How do i get this ID (my app is not published to the market yet)?

2: The test ads says dont forget to turn testing mode off before publishing, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have submitted a support ticket, which has already been answered from our records. If not, this thread should help solve your problem!

http://support.mobclix.com/entries/483832-my-app-only-displays-mobclix-ads-or-mobclix-test-ads-i-want-to-have-it-display-real-ads

Let us know if you have any other questions.

Thanks!

Mobclix Support Team